# Get value Registry not working when run on IIS but working when run from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, iis

This is my code to getvalue from REGISTRY, when i run directly from Visual studio its working fine but when i run from IIS the value always null.

```
        RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
   @"Software\Indomaret\POS\Database",
    false); //writable - this will fail without proper access
        string sDefault = rk.GetValue("Server").ToString();

        ASPxButton1.Text = sDefault;
```

Comment: IIS will be running under a service or AppPool account and very likely won't have a Software\IndoMaret key. If you configure the ApplicationPool to use your account to run, does it work?

Comment: @jessehouwing how to configure it i don't understand sorry i'm newbie.. :D

Comment: See: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run from Visual Studio, you typically run it under your account which is normally an administrator account. You'll have complete read/write access to the whole registry. So you might have created the key without any hiccups.

When you run under IIS, you most probably run under a particular APP pool account.
This account will mostly have read-only permissions to the registry, but not write permissions. So you just need to ensure that the key exists for you to read it as an app pool account.

In order to verify, try to write the key using the app pool account. if you don't get an access exception, you should be able to read it.

if not, you need to either give write permissions (if your app is what is writing the key) or ensure that the key exists under that user in the registry.

Comment: how to configure it i don't understand sorry i'm newbie.. :D